# I have a JSON with several fields and a key of keys, how can i by $resorce of angularjs bring only this key of Keys?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-resource

My Json is this

```
[
{
    "usuario": {
        "id": 2,
        "username": "licorera1"
    },
    "productos": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "descripcion": "Botella",
            "precio": "1500000",
            "marca": {
                "nombre": "Red Label",
                "tipo": {
                    "descripcion": "Whiskey"
                }
            },
            "imagen": "http://192.168.0.12:8000/media/producto/redlabel.png"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "descripcion": "Media Botella",
            "precio": "50000",
            "marca": {
                "nombre": "Nectar",
                "tipo": {
                    "descripcion": "Aguardiente"
                }
            },
            "imagen": "http://192.168.0.12:8000/media/producto/nectarrojo_qgCTYsx.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

and what i want to do is to get only de object "productos".

the entire url of the json is http://192.168.0.12:8000/api/productos_licorera/?pk=2&licorera=

so in my services.js i use the $resource to get de JSON

this is my services.js

```
(function (){

angular.module('productos.services',['ngResource'])

.factory('LicoresService',['$resource',function($resource){
return $resource('http://192.168.0.12:8000/api/productos_licorera/', {}, {
  query: {method:'GET', params:{pk:2,licorera:''}, isArray:true}
    });
 }]);
})();
```

and this is my controller.js

```
(function(){

angular.module('productos.controllers',[])
.controller('LicoresController',['$scope','$http', '$resource', 'LicoresService',function($scope, $http,$resource, LicoresService){
    var licores;
    var show = false; 
    $scope.licores = LicoresService.query();
}])
.controller('TabsController', function () {
  this.tab = 4;
  this.selectTab = function (tab) {
    this.tab = tab;
      console.log(this.tab);
  };
});    
})();
```

i need to get in the variable "licores" not all the Json, just only the "productos" object.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a 'transport' format. You can't transport a partial JSON.
Though, after you have parsed JSON to a regular javascript object, you can pick the key you like:

```
$scope.licores = JSON.parse(LicoresService.query())[0].licores;
```

Hope this can help you...

Comment: Thanks for your help but it doesn't work´s.                                                                            I'm thinking of something like get ({id: '1'}), but that it can be used with the key I need, something like get({product}). there is something like that?